# SQL to select questions user didn't answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

**user** (user_id)
**question** (question_id)
**answer** (question_id, answer_id, user_id)

How can I select the questions that a user didn't answer?
Thank you.

Comment: With a properly structured query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question appears to be missing some information as user is not associated with question or answer in any way.  Assuming that answer has (user_id, question_id, answer_id) or that answer only has answered questions in it you can do

```
SELECT question_id
FROM question q
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM answer a WHERE a.question_id = q.question_id);
```

Comment: yes, i forgot 'user_id'. Thank you so much. It worked here.